# Shallow copy of tracked Entity

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, copy, clone

I'm dealing with Fluent NHibernate and versioning of objects.

What I actually need is to create a shallow copy of an object.
I tried using MemberwiseClone() which seems to the right thing, but obviously this
clones the ID also. Fluent NHibernate will complain when the cloned object is committed to the database that there's already an object with that ID.

How can I tell the automapper to assign a new ID to the cloned object?

Regards,
Erik

Answer (score 2):

1) `clone = MemberwiseClone(); clone.Id = 0;`

or

2) Implement `object ICloneable.Clone()` and for convenience `MyType Clone()`

i would prefer 2)